# Set chunk size for LWP get callback

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

The [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) module allows using callback to read web content in chunks.

```
$r = $ua->get($url, ':content_cb' => sub
{
  my ($chunk, $resp, $proto) = @_;
  # ...
});
```

It seems that the chunk size is preset to 16384 bytes, which is very small for me.

How can I set the chunks to be of a different size, …let's say 4MB, i.e. `4*1024*1024` ?

I added `:read_size_hint` as follows, but seen no effect.

```
$r = $ua->get($url, ':read_size_hint' => 4*1024*1024, ':content_cb' => sub
{
  my ($chunk, $resp, $proto) = @_;
  # ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:read_size_hint` is only a hint given to `sysread` of the underlying socket module. This does not mean that there will be that much data read at once, only that they might be if they are already available.

How much is actually available and thus can be returned by `sysread` depends on how fast the sender will send data (sysread will not wait for more but just return what's available so far) and how large the sockets read buffer is.

In case of TLS it will also depend on the TLS record size used by the sender, i.e. a single `sysread` will not return results spanning multiple TLS records. Since the maximum record size in TLS is 16384 any larger settings for `:read_size_hint` have therefore no effect.

Comment: It sounds like this `:read_size_hint` "feature" is good just for lowering the chunk size.

Comment: @Ωmega: It is mainly for tuning the trade-off between memory use and performance. If you had other goals by using this feature it might be the wrong approach. Maybe describe what you were trying to achieve, i.e why you need to work with larger chunks.

Comment: I am using this part of code in the script where I am reading an external PDF file from OneDrive (using MS Graph API) and proxying its content as output, with `Content-Disposition: attachment;` header to force downloading the file locally. While it works smoothly, it is very slow, and neither OneDrive nor network are limiting factors.

Comment: @Ωmega: Are you sure the read size is the problem then? You are basically building a TLS intercepting proxy here, i.e. there is TLS encryption/decryption going on from LWP to the server and maybe also from your proxy to your client. And maybe there is more overhead on other places. And maybe there is also more traffic if no Accept-Encoding is sent but the download could have been compressed for transport.

Comment: LWP is slow. Check out Net::Curl

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is entirely at the sending server's discretion.

What I've done is accumulate their response in the `response_data` [handler](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#add_handler), until some criterion at which further action is taken.

Another option is to let the object accumulate it and use other handlers.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed-size chunks:

```perl
my $msg_size = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
my $buf = '';

my $response = $ua->get( $url, 
   ':content_cb' => sub {
      $buf .= shift;
      while ( length( $buf ) >= $msg_size ) {
         process( substr( $buf, 0, $msg_size, "" ), @_ );
      }
   },
);

!length( $buf )
   or die( "Premature EOF\n" );
```